# C++ Return entire null separated string

Tags: c++, char

I need to give a function a null terminated character sequence, but I can't figure out how to go from string literal ultimately to a char pointer. Problem is demonstrated here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("this\0is a\0null separated\0string");
  std::cout << "The size of str is " << str.size() << " bytes.\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

my current code works..

```
    std::string tmp = g_apidefs[i].ret_val +'.'+ g_apidefs[i].parm_types +'.'+ g_apidefs[i].parm_names +'.'+ g_apidefs[i].html_help;

    size_t length = 1+strlen(tmp.c_str());
    g_apidefs[i].dyn_def = new char[length];
    memcpy(g_apidefs[i].dyn_def, tmp.c_str(), length);
    char* p = g_apidefs[i].dyn_def;
    while (*p) { if (*p=='.') *p='\0'; ++p; }

    ok &= rec->Register(g_apidefs[i].regkey_def, g_apidefs[i].dyn_def) != 0;
```

...it turns `.` into `\0`, but is there any way to just have `\0` in the first place? I was originally using strdup (a few less lines of code) but had some platform-specific incompatibility issues.

I'm wondering if there's a C++11 or C++14 way of dealing with this?

Comment: You need to tell `std::string` how long the initializer is. If you let it work it out itself it will stop counting chars at the first \0.

Comment: "String literal"?  What language are you coming from?  

std::string tolerates non-terminating \0 characters just fine - why do you find it necessary to replace them with . characters?  Just pass a length in the constructor.

Comment: I guess I didn't know how to get the length of the string literal in the first place with null chars. Answer below shows how.

Comment: You'd call that a string with embedded nulls.  They are often ended with a double null.  I've seen these referred to as multistrings. There was another name to it as well, but I forgot what that is.  It's a fairly atypical use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `char` array and initialize your string using iterators to this array, e.g.:

```
template <int N>
std::string make_string(char const (&array)[N]) {
    return std::string(array, array + N);
}

int main() {
    std::string s = make_string("foo\0bar");
}
```

As defined the string will also contain the terminating null character. Just subtract `1` if that's not desired. This works with all versions of C++.

Comment: woah, never seen that kind of usage of template with `<int N>` and `&array` `[N]`, where can I get more info on this kind of syntax?

Comment: It is a non-type template. That's fairly normal actually. The more interesting realization is the use of a reference to an array to figure out the length. That not a new idea, either: it is around nearly 20 years...

Comment: consider using `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: ahh sorry, my questions wasn't clear. I actually need to do something like this: `new_str = make_str(str1 + '\0' + str2)`. Can your function be tweaked to accomplish that?

Comment: Assuming `str1` happens to be a `std::string`, you can do that anyway: there are `operator+()` overloaded for `std::string` taking a `char`, a `char const*` or a `std::string`. To get a `char const*` from that you can use `c_str()`. Note, however, that functions consuming just a `char const*` will stop reading upon the first embedded null character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own answer as an alternative just in case someone finds it useful:

```
std::vector<std::string> str_vect ={ str1,str2,str3,str4 };

std::vector<char> char_arr
for (const auto& str : str_vect) {
    char_arr.insert(char_arr.end(), str.begin(), str.end());
    char_arr.push_back('\0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I really needed, it's really simple, not sure how I spent hours trying to figure it out

```
// str is a global variable, so it is safe to reference it with &
string str = str1 + '\0' + str2 + '\0' + str3 + '\0' + str4;
func_that_needs_null_separated_str(&str[0]);
```

Thanks @Dietmar Kühl for the little tip that finally lead me to this conclusion.

Well good. Now this Stackoverflow question has answers to two problems dealing with null characters.